# Getting information from image using mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a home page where database value are showing (e.g. a image and few information) [image]

My problem is whenever i click on the image it jumps to another page and show all the pictures that are store in database,but i want the clicked one.

Here is my 1st page home_page.php code

```
<?php

        $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "registration_data");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM add_data";

        $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $image = $row['image'];

            echo "<div id='img_div'>";
                ?><a href = "Details.php?image=' . $image . '"><?php echo "<img src='images/".$row['image']."' >";?></a><?php
                echo "<p>Description: ".$row['add_description']." </p>";
                echo "<p>Cetegory: ".$row['catagory']. "</p>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
?>
```

And this is my second page where i want to show only clicked image information.(Details.php)

```
<?php

$image = intval($_GET["image"]);


$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "registration_data");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM add_data where 'id' = $image ";

        $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

            $imageShow = $row['image'];
            print $imageShow;
        }



?>
```

Comment: add `LIMIT 1` to the SQL in the Details.php. But you have to debug it all to ge the real error. And tablenames/fields are not written in quotes like `'id'`  do `id` or `\`id\``. Keep this in mind: `SELECT 1+1` or `SELECT 'a' 'B'` First result is `2` second is `aB`

Comment: selecting everything and dumping it into the same cell is wrong here.  rtry  $sql = "SELECT image, Description, Category FROM add_data WHERE category =* " Then you will split out each column into it's own web element.  W3C will have a guide for this too BTW, but this also leaves you open to SQL injection. You alswo might want to change your variables, i.e. $sql1, $sql2 to prevent them being called by mistake.

Comment: @Ben Coughlan `same cell` ? Maybe same id but each image has it own div. And in the second part, he only wants one entry and that the problem here... more ar printed. And there is no SQL injection here, did you see: `intval($_GET["image"]);`  Please point out only real errors

Comment: You don't need a db connect in the results page simply `echo` the image where you would like it in the page

Comment: @chop62 is correct here actually. unless you have a thumbnail image and a high resolution image.

Comment: Thanks everyone,i solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

So, if your initial page for calling the image is something like:

```
<body>
<img src="getImage.php?**id=1**" width="175" height="200" />
</body>
```

Then getImage.php is

```
<?php

  $id = $_GET['id'];
  // do some validation here to ensure id is safe

  $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
  mysql_select_db("dvddb");
  $sql = "SELECT dvdimage FROM dvd WHERE id=**$id"**;
  $result = mysql_query("$sql");
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  mysql_close($link);

  header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
  echo $row['dvdimage'];
?>
```

You're currently passing row, rather than ID.

Your table isn't telling anyone what cell is which, you should be using a primary key as a reference id.

so your SQL should select the table colums and assign them to values within each row, then you pass in the query to pull back the image with a certain primary key.

i.e. row is a PHP value, you need to extract and reference a DB value, a primary key. i.e. ImageID.